# When is it necessary to include/exclude the base call for MVC action filters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Working with a legacy application, I noticed two different implementations for MVC filters following the pattern below:

Example 1:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TestFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Code here...
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Code here...
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TestFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Code here...
    }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Code here...
    }
}
```

Is there a reason to include/exclude the base call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case there is no point in calling `base` method as you derive from an `abstract` class which default implementation is empty (from decompiled sources):

```
/// <summary>
/// Occurs before the action method is invoked.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="actionContext">The action context.</param>
public virtual void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Occurs after the action method is invoked.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="actionExecutedContext">The action executed context.</param>
public virtual void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
}
```

However if one day, the implementation of `ActionFilterAttribute` changes you could benefit from this calling the base method. But this is just hypothetical and it's up to you as it depends on what new feature this class could have if any.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not have a concept that let one to express "derived class must/must not call base class implementations". There is `abastract` that somewhat helps on first level of hierarchy to say "derived must provide implementation and must not call base", but that have drawbacks for optional methods like in action filters.

As result it is not possible to make general decision when one should/must/must not  call base implementation.

In case of ActionFilters base implementation of `OnXxxx` methods is empty, so there is no difference whether you call it or not. It would make difference if you inherit next layer of classes (like `SpecialFilter`: `BaseFilter` : `ActionFilter`) - in such case not calling base class will make significant difference (which may be intentional, hopefully it will have comment in the code).

In places I worked it is custom to call base implementation unless it is explicitly prohibited in documentation. Cases when base class is not called usually have comment added with reason why.